# renderRequest in expression language

Tags: java, jsp, el, portlet, websphere-portal

Cn we be able to use Expression language for `renderRequest.getPreferences().getValue().` Currently, I am using scriplet in the jsp page and I want to avoid scriptlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using EL 2.2 or higher, expressions of this form should work:

```
${request.getPreferences().getValue('foo', 'some default')}
```

Generally, this is only available on Java EE 6 platforms.

On earlier versions you should be able to use an expression like this:

```
${request.preferences.map['foo']}
```

Note that this will return [an array](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletPreferences.html#getMap%28%29). If you want a single value, you may need to employ a layer of indirection.

*Caveat: none of this code has been tested.*

Comment: I am using    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%> and I don't think its 2.2.

Comment: @user525146 - If you're using a version before WebSphere Application Server 8, you probably don't have it.

Comment: +1. And confirmation: it works. I have two additions. 1) since version 2.0 of Portlet one can get access to *portletPreferences* right in the JSP (provided the `<portlet:defineObjects />` was declared in that JSP), like: `${portletPreferences.getValue('foo', 'some default')}`. The full list of objects available to JSP sinve version 2.0 can be seen here (along with the comparison to previous version): [JSR286: defineObjects Tag (variables available in the JSP)](https://blogs.oracle.com/deepakg/entry/jsr286_defineobjects_tag).

Comment: 2) For the sake of completeness: to get the specific value using the second solution (a map), one can reference the returned array, like: `${portletPreferences.map['foo'][0]}`. Maybe it's obvious, but again - just in case.